# print only decimal places of double

Tags: c, printf, double, decimal

I want to print only the decimal places of a `double` with the `printf` statement in C. But not the first decimal places if they are 0. For example my doubles are

```
double number1 = 0.95;
double number2 = 0.05;
```

`number 1` should be printed as `95` and `number 2` should be printed as `5`.

Comment: Then show what you tried.

Comment: You can use `sprintf()` and `strchr()` ... but there's no function directly doing what you're asking here, so this question looks like a request to write code.

Comment: what do you mean with "decimal places"? Binary floating point numbers have no "decimal places"

Comment: No arithmetical method as any operation can change precision of the result. sprtintf it and extract what you need.

Comment: Thanks, `sprintf()` did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *trailingDecimals(char *buffer, size_t bufsize, double val)
{
    static const char *empty = "";
    snprintf(buffer, bufsize, "%.20f", val);
    char *result = strchr(buffer, '.');
    if (!result) return empty;
    while (*++result == '0');
    char *tail = buffer + strlen(buffer) - 1;
    if (*tail == '0')
    {
        while (*--tail == '0');
        *++tail = 0;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    double test = 12.00506;
    char buf[64];
    puts(trailingDecimals(buf, 64, test));
}
```

But be aware of precision issues, you might get more places than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) and skip the "0." from your output buffer.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean - and show how this differs from the other answers. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.